# Drupal integration with xero

Tags: drupal

Not sure if I am on the correct forum, I do not know anything about coding...
I am having a website built that is on drupal platform it is very custom (as my developer has said), essentially  it will be raising 2 invoices one to the client and one commission invoice to me, I want the commission invoice to be able to be extracted into xero so that when it is paid I can mark it off and be able to bank reconcile. He said that this can not be done as it was built on drupal - just wondered if any one is able to advise me as to whether it can be done? is it really expensive for it to be done? or if I am asking in completely the wrong place? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You will probably not get very useful help on that matter on Stackoverflow. You're better off hiring a Drupal consultant/programmer to take a look at your situation. Regarding the statement `this can not be done as it was built on drupal` this should be contested. It might not be reasonable (time, money costs, etc) but certainly it's not impossible just because it's made in Drupal.

Answer (score 0):

What you're asking for is not impossible as already stated and xero does have an api, but it is likely that this will cost more than the need.

Best to get another estimate from another developer.